# selective deletion of lines between two patterns

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, scripting

I have a file which contains following content,

```
Hello world Unix!!
Its bright world
Current time is HH:mm:ss
Next action plan is item #3
End of task.
Thank you.


Hello world Linux!!
All actions completed.
End of Activity.
Thanks.
```

I would like to selectively delete all the lines that contain keyword, "world" and also all the subsequent lines until a line with specific set of keywords (Example, "Activity" or "task") are encountered.

Desired output :

```
End of task.
Thank you.
End of Activity.
Thanks.
```

Comment: what happened to the blank lines? They weren't between a (new) "world" and "activity" or "task".

Comment: Blank lines can be retained or deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ awk  -v f=1 '/world/{f=0} /Activity|task/{f=1} f' File
End of task.
Thank you.


End of Activity.
Thanks.
```

How it works:

1. `-v f=1`

   Create an awk variable `f` and set it to `1`.
2. `/world/{f=0}`

   If the current line contains `world`, set variable `f` to zero.
3. `/Activity|task/{f=1}`

   If the line contains either `Activity` or `task`, then set `f` to `1`.

   Note that `world` above and `Activity` or `task` here are treated as regular expressions.  Also, they are case-sensitive.
4. `f`

   If `f` is nonzero, print the line.

#### To also delete blank lines

```
$ awk  -v f=1 '/world/{f=0} /Activity|task/{f=1} f && /./' File
End of task.
Thank you.
End of Activity.
Thanks.
```

`f && /./` tells awk to print the line only if `f` is non-zero **and** the line contains at least one character (of any kind).

Answer (score 3):

Not as pretty as the awk solution, but since the OP tagged the question with **sed** too, here goes:

```
#with blank lines
sed '/world/,/task\|Activity/{//!d};/world/d' file

#without blank lines
sed '/world/,/task\|Activity/{//!d};/world\|^$/d' file
```

Note the use of `//`, which means the previous regular expression used :)